# What tools are best for writing resumes?

Tags: job-search, resume

What do people use to write resumes these days? Which tools are the best. I've seen lots of LaTex based resumes (there's even a [tag for it on this stackexchange site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resume)). I'm guessing this is niche and unnecessary for most job applications. Is a plain text editor like Word sufficient, and just make a copy of a similar resume each time you need a different version? Are there any templates or resume builders that are recommended?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend a standard word processor.  Any of MS Word, Libre Office, or Google Sheets will do.

You can do fancy things with LaTeX that would be difficult at best with a word processor, but the result will be suboptimal for crucial parts of the hiring process.  If the only people looking at it were humans then a PDF or hard copy would be fine.

However the first stage of the hiring process is generally automated screening via a computer based system.  They don't care about the fancy formatting you did to make it look pretty to humans, all they want is a stream of text to process.  They normally won't speak any sort of TeX, some won't speak .PDF either.  Even for the ones that do support .pdf, the way the text is stored is harder for automated systems to process in order.  You can often see examples of this by opening a pdf, doing select all, copy, and then pasting into a text editor only to see weird line breaks, missing spaces, and (especially with more complex layouts) text not in a natural reading order.

While formats like .docx have their own problems, the need to support humans navigating a cursor through the document using the right arrow key mean that they do store the information needed to normally extract the text in single a coherent stream to feed into whatever keyword matching tool HR uses to do their initial screening.

If you're being hired for a company whose core competency is LaTeX (this is different from being hired to use it at a normal company), the above might not apply, but 99.% of the time a word processed file will be the best option.

Comment: Or even a plantext file and a non-wordprocessing editor.

Answer (score 1):

For writing it, you use the tool that you find the best and are more familiar/experienced with.

**However**, have in mind a very important aspect: *one thing is the tool for writing the resume and another thing is the format you export it to (or the format required by the company you are applying to)*.

You could write it in Word, Google Docs, LibreOffice, LaTex, Notepad on a .txt file, any other online tool, using `nano/vim` and typing it on terminal, etc... the options are many, but always have in mind the fact that regardless of the tool chosen to *write* it **you will most likely end up being required to submit it as PDF or .docx** (PDF usually for humans/printing, .docx usually for automated parsing of resumes for keywords).

Thus, make sure that the tool you chose is capable of exporting it to PDF and/or .docx, or that there is an easy way for you to obtain such output formats... with that in mind LaTex may not be ideal nor trivial to convert to .docx or PDF (not a LaTex expert though...)

Comment: Conversion of LaTeX to PDF is trivial. To Word format not so much...

Comment: @JonCuster yeah, that's what I recalled from when I used LaTex frequently... there's even a horror story at my former Uni... some students did all their Thesis/Graduation Project in LaTex, becuase it was "innovative" etc etc., only to find out that the Uni required all graduation projects to be submitted in word format... they ended up translating/rewriting all the document :'( as there was no easy way to convert it to that format

Answer (score 0):

I just use Word.

Normally I'll find a template online that is the new hotness, then edit it to be applicable to my skills and experience and then save it. Sometimes if there's a job I'm particularly interested in, I might tweak my CV to emphasize certain projects/skills slightly more than others - but generally I have a CV and use my Cover Letter to add any additional nuance that I want.